# equal = being better?

Tags: vocabulary

> **Scalar comparison of equality indicates “at least equal”**
>  In the absence of indications to the contrary, a scalar [= ‘clever’ in
>   [i] below] comparison of equality is interpreted as “at least equal”,
>   not “exactly equal”:
>
> i) Jill is as clever as Liz.  [Jill may be cleverer]
>  ii) Jill
>   isn’t as clever as Liz  [Jill must be less clever]
>
> Example [i] is consistent with Jill being cleverer than Liz: we can
>   say *Jill’s as clever as Liz, somewhat more so in fact*. [n] Scalar
>   equality therefore normally exclude only the relation of inferiority:
>   it gives a lower bound. . . . . .
>
> ---
>
> [n] This can indeed apply also to **equal** itself, as in *Kim is the
>   equal of Pat when it comes to solving crossword puzzles* (which is
>   consistent with Kim being better) or *We hope to equal last year’s
>   profit* (consistent with bettering it). (CGEL, p.1100~1101)

1. as ~ as:
   Does the phrase “at least equal” refer to *as ~ as construction* or one of **as**s? 
   (I want to know whether the meaning comes from the structure or the lexical meaning.)
2. equal:
   I don’t find any lexical source that *equal* implies being better. Is there any dictionary saying the meaning?

Comment: You're mistakenly assuming *"Jill is as clever as Liz"* means the same as *"Jill is **at least** as clever as Liz"*. In actual fact, if people really have that second meaning in mind, they'll normally either include ***at least***, or they'll say something like *"Jill is as clever as Liz - if not **cleverer**"* (or maybe ***more clever***, since that particular adjective doesn't sit well with the ***-er*** suffix).

Comment: Yes, I'm with FumbleFingers on this one. Despite the text you've quoted, I would naturally assume that "Jill is as clever as Liz" means that the two are equally clever, or quite nearly so. If I meant something different, I'd add qualifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is in the negative statement: "Jill isn't as clever as Liz." 100% of native speakers will interpret this to mean "Jill is less clever than Liz." *No one* will think it could mean that Jill is much, much cleverer than Liz, unless the statement is meant as a joke.

Back to the positive statement, then, "Jill is as clever as Liz." Yes, this leaves room for Jill to be much cleverer than Liz. I could nod agreement and say "At least." If Jill were far cleverer than Liz, though, it would feel too understated and I might shake my head in disagreement.

The same thing happens with "equal." If I say "You are not my equal," that means "You are my inferior." (Barring weird cases where I'm explaining politeness rules or something.) But if I say "You are my equal" then I don't think anyone would interpret that to mean other than what it literally says.

This is all the domain of *pragmatics* by the way, not syntax or semantics, so you won't find it in a dictionary. Pragmatics studies (among other things) the implications we make by the things we *don't* say. For example, when we say "A or B" we usually mean "but not both." If both were an option, we'd have said "A and B" to begin with.